# Double calls on jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem, I will try to explain:

Im using the following function (ajax jQuery)

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php?controller=Group&action=getInfoAjax",
        data: "parameter="+parameter,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(message)
        { .....
```

Some times (I'm not sure how to reproduce it) the ajax call is performed twice, and the following can be seen on firebug:

- The first one stays thinking and the second one seems to be completed.
- Both contains the answer on the "Response" tab.
- The success function is never called.

I thought that it was because the user was clicking twice, but I already placed some code to avoid that. In my last test I saw how the first one was thinking and with "no reason" the second started.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Is there any chance the AJAX is called in the callback to an animation (or something similar)?

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your complete html/js, it could be difficult to suggest a fix. But the following could be a great work around. Ben Alman's Debounce and Throttle plugin will be a life safer in such situations.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

In your case a debounce could be sufficient. You may have to experiment with a delay of 10-200ms. In those special cases where you see two ajax calls being made, debounce will make a single call.

For example, I use debounce in all ajax calls that are to be fired on "text" box keyup event. debounce, kind of queues multiple rapidly fired successive calls. when the successive calls stop for atleast 'delay' time, debounce makes one call.